# How to use EditText to retrieve a string in Android?

Tags: android, sms, android-edittext

I'm trying to create an app to get a phone no and a message as input from the user and send an sms.
Unfortunately, the EditText has been causing problems. Here's the code I've used. Could someone please correct it for me? thanks!

```
public class SmsActivity extends Activity   
{
    EditText et1,et2;  
    Button send;  
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);  
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2)…  

        final String phno = et1.getText().toString();   
        final String msg= et2.getText().toString();   

        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);  
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
        {
            public void onClick(View v)  
            {
                sendsms(phno,msg);  
            }
        });
    }


    private void sendsms(String phno,String msg)  
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();  
        sms.sendTextMessage(phno, null, msg, null, null);  
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have ellipsize character at the line `et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2)… `?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting your Strings in `onCreate()` method (which is called only once, as even mentioned in comment in your code =) ) to values in `EditText`s, which I assume are empty at that moment, and so in your `OnClickListener` you are using that initial values, which never change. What you need for your `OnClickListener` is

```
send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);  
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
    public void onClick(View v)  
    {
        String phno = et1.getText().toString();   
        String msg= et2.getText().toString();   

        sendsms(phno,msg);  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to help even though you are being extremely vague.

In these lines:

`et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2)…`

Are et1 and et2 the actual ids of these forms as stated in your layout xml? Did you intentionally miss the semi-colon after 'et2)'?

Also, you don't need to make the Strings a final, though I guess thats a personal choice.

Another thing...

[This pdf will help you do what you are trying to do.](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/sites/default/files/users/21/file/Chapter%208%209781118087299-2.pdf)

Comment: yeah, Strings have to be final to be used inside inner class.